# how to resolve this error in ubuntu instance in ec2?

Tags: apt, amazon-ec2

I was trying to host my project which uses tkinter. when I enter the running command of my project, it showed I was lacking some requirements like tensorflow, opencv, keras and some version differences in pip, so I tried to install them. After, when I tried to run the code it showed this error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)

E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-187:~$ Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

And I was stuck with this. I tried a lot of things but nothing goes with the Ubuntu instance. Can you please help?

Comment: As the error asks.  Are you root ?

Comment: An error message is useless without seeing the code that caused the error.  In this case, what's lacking is the actual command that you ran.